# Refresh loop of custom posts (div) after new post is published

Tags: ajax

**GOAL**
Wondering if following should be done, I would like to (ajax?) refresh not necessary only (custom) post type loop or div

example custom post query :

```
<div class="refreshed posts">
<?php

global $post;

$myposts = get_posts('post_type=employer&numberposts=5&orderby=modified&offset=0');

foreach($myposts as $post) :

setup_postdata($post);

?>
</div>
```

**CONCLUSION**

Auto refresh posts can help my website users to see that when for example somebody submits a post type employer entry, at the same moment all online users can see all updated "employer" posts including that one submitted post. I would like to avoid using plugins. In the similar manner uses facebook etc their notifications (I believe they scheduled to refresh in minute intervals)

Comment: With the [Wordpress 3.6 heartbit Api](http://wpengineer.com/2549/wordpress-pulse-heartbeat-api/) this should be easier. With current wordpress version you have to _play_ with ajax and `setInterval()`

Comment: I have installed Wordpress 3.6 Beta version, how can I achieve it with that version?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/23216/heartbeat-test-plugin.php)?

Comment: G.M this is a correct answer pls. answer my question below and I will mark that as correct, thanks to you I have found probably already working plugin which notifies about new posts, it will need some further implementations but it is very good start thanks to you , plugin here [link](https://github.com/micc83/wp-heartbeat-notify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Wordpress 3.6 heartbit](http://wpengineer.com/2549/wordpress-pulse-heartbeat-api/) Api this should be easier.

With previous Wordpress version you have to play with ajax and js `setInterval()` function.

### Edit

@Daniel Foltynek suggest this [plugin](https://github.com/micc83/wp-heartbeat-notify).